# Getting question marks in hebrew values from SQL in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, encoding

I know that there is alot of variation of this question in stackOverflow, but none of then helped me in this problem... I'm tring to build website with java (JSPs, servlets, and more), I'm using mysql 5.6, Java 7, and apache tomcat 7. when I tried to get data from mysql using java, It displayed only question marks. At first, I thought it is only problem of display, but when I checked the string in java, In was an actual question marks, with ascii value of 63... I'm using connector class that I wrote  for handling sql, here is the code:

```
package classes;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

public class Connector {

private Connection con;


public Connector(String userName, String password) {
    MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setServerName("localhost");
    ds.setPort(3306);
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection("root","16180339887");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void executeUpdate(String sql) {
    try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(sql);
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String[][] executeQuery(String sql) {
    String[][] query = null;
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        int column = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        result.last();
        query = new String[result.getRow()][column];

        result.beforeFirst();
        int i = 0;
        while (result.next()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                query[i][j] = result.getString(j + 1);
            i++;
        }

        result.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return query;
}
```

}

here is the database creation code:

```
private static void createDB() {
    Connector c = new Connector("root", "16190339887");
    c.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE grade4troop1");
    c.executeUpdate("USE grade4troop1");
    c.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE group1m(firstName VARCHAR(10),"
            + "lastName VARCHAR(10), id VARCHAR(9), father VARCHAR(10),"
            + "mother VARCHAR(10), address VARCHAR(30), motherPhone VARCHAR(10),"
            + "fatherPhone VARCHAR(10), homePhone VARCHAR(10), birthday DATE)");
    c.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO group1m VALUES('דורון', 'בצלאלי', '773916104', 'מיכה', 'ורד', 'הברוש', '0529251293', '0503085079', '046289476','2003-05-17')");
}
```

I don't know if the data corrupts when I insert it to the db, or when I'm tring to use it. anyway, I'm sorry if I have mistakes in my english, and if any information is missing, just ask.

UPDATE:
I made sure that my jsp page is `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`, and the meta tag is: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`.

I  also changed the db statment to: `CREATE DATABASE grade4troop1 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin`, and it didn't work. I tried to add `SET NAMES utf8`, didn't work either.

When I tried to SELECT from the console, I get question marks just like in java, so I think the data is corrupted when it is inserted into the db.

I'm really desperate here, please help me guys

Comment: if you're getting back actual question marks when you fetch... then I'd assume it's getting corrupted when you insert the data. Have you checked that the character-encoding of your database supports the characters you want to store in it? (utf-8 ? unicode?)

Comment: Have you trying viewing the data by doing a SELECT from the mysql console?

Comment: I didn't checked the encoding of my db, I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps

1.Change your create database query like this;

```
CREATE DATABASE grade4troop1 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

2.Check your JSP pages have contain this line;

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

3.If your are using eclipse, you should doing [these step](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/).